# Carrierwave uploads don't appear on POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, railscasts

I'm following the [Railscast tutorial for Carrierwave uploads](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads?view=asciicast), and have the same files set up. An upload works fine if I upload a file via the console, but my form doesn't seem to post correctly.

I've got my basic form, which includes:

```
<%= f.label :receipt %><br>
<%= f.file_field :receipt %>
```

Rails 4 does automatically include a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` tag on the form.

When I submit the form, I take a look at the server logs. The upload shows up in the parameters:

```
"receipt"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fcb25c624e0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/ty/yks2xd9n76z9p49qzprvt1900000gn/T/RackMultipart20130903-53712-17zblz4>, 
@original_filename="Avatar.jpg", 
@content_type="image/jpeg", 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"expense[receipt]\"; filename=\"Avatar.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">},
```

However, the INSERT statement doesn't include any mention of my receipt field or file. There isn't any error. The file is not uploaded to the directory I specified in Carrierwave either.

Any ideas on what might be going wrong here? This is not a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815569/rails-file-field-does-not-upload-anything) which was an issue with jQuery Mobile. I'm really stumped on what's going on.

**Edit:** I should probably include my model as well:

```
class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :receipt, ReceiptUploader
end
```

I have a stock uploader class as well, generated by Carrierwave:

```
class ReceiptUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    storage :file

    def store_dir
        "receipts"
    end
end
```

**Edit 2:** Here is my controller for creating an expense:

```
def new
  @expense = Expense.new
end

def create
  @expense = Expense.new(expense_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @expense.save
      format.html { redirect_to @expense, notice: 'Expense was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @expense }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @expense.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What's your controller method look like? Have you tried using [pry](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) to check if the parameter is being filtered out before it gets into Expense#create or Expense#update?

Comment: Updated the original post with my controller method for new and create. It's the stock scaffold generation code. On the other hand, I installed pry but I'm not sure what I should be looking for with it.

Comment: Basically I want to know if expense_params[:receipt] has the expected value. You may need to permit it.

Comment: Unbelievable. Serious rookie mistake here - that was the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the params wasn't permitting the upload to go through. Rookie mistake.